# Linux Mint 19v1 how to change the behaviour of K3b with a blank DVD in a removable drive?

Tags: runtime-error, k3b

This is a fresh install of Linux Mint 19v1 Tessa

The system asks what do you want to do with a blank disk?

I choose "Run K3b" as this is logical but...
While running K3b to make several copies of a DVD video at each iteration of the next copy, when a fresh blank DVD is inserted, another iteration of "K3b" is started causing confusion over which iteration and which dialogue window(s) needs to be closed without damaging the legitimate current K3b copy process!

So to clear what appears to be an application error, i.e. the application fails to check first if a prior copy of itself already exists, to then open a courtesy dialogue of:

"There is already a copy of K3b running, 
do you really want to start a fresh copy? 
(Y/N)"

But failing this, how can I now change the default behaviour of the DVD drive whenever a fresh disk is inserted? This is not made clear after the initial request for default behaviour! (another programming error after entrapping the end-user, then ignoring the needs of the end-user/non-programmer!)

Compassionate answers only please, all answers gratefully received, thank you.
P.s. In Linux, how many other programs bother to check for prior iterations + a courtesy dialogue at first?